# Notation for presentation of a quotient of a free group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, definition, group-presentation

> Let $I,J$ be sets and $\mathbf{r}=(r_{j})_{j\in J}$ a family of
>   elements of the free group $F(I)$. For $i\in I$ let $\phi_i$ denote
>   the canonical homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $F(I)$.
>
> Let  $$N(\mathbf{r}):=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{y\ |\ (\exists
>  g)(\exists a)(g\in F(I)\land
>  a\in\left(\bigcup\left\{r_j,r_j^{-1}\right\}\right)^{[1,n]}\land
>  y=\prod_{i=1}^nga_ig^{-1})\right\};$$ in other words, $N(\mathbf{r})$
>   is the normal subgroup of $F(I)$ generated by the $r_j$. Let
>   $\pi:F(I)\rightarrow F(I)/N(\mathbf{r})$ be the canonical
>   homomorphism. For $i\in I$ let $\tau_i=\pi(\phi_i(1))$. Then
>   $(\tau_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of elements of $F(I)/N(\mathbf{r})$.
>   Then the group $F(I)/N(\mathbf{r})$ is defined by the generators
>   $\tau_i$ and the relators $r_j$.
>
> Now, suppose $I=[1,n]$ and $J=[1,m]$. Let $r_j=u_j^{-1}v_j$ for
>   $u_j,v_j\in F(I)$ and $j\in J$. Then we say that $F(I)/N(\mathbf{r})$
>   is defined by the presentation
>   $$\langle\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_n;u_1=v_1,\ldots,u_m=v_m\rangle.$$

I don't understand why we write $u_j=v_j$ ($j\in J$) in the symbol above? Isn't it rather the case that the equivalence classes of $u_j,v_j$ are equal: i.e. $\pi(u_j)=\pi(v_j)$?

Comment: So, just to clarify: when we write $u_j=v_j$ in the presentation, we really mean that the equivalence classes of $u_j,v_j$ are equal. Correct?

Comment: Just saw your edited comment. Thanks

Comment: I think I disagree with @Dietrich. Formally, the relations $u_i=v_i$ mean that the words $u_iv_i^{-1}$ form a normal generating set for the kernel. *In practice*, the abuse of notation equating words and equivalence classes is common and helpful, but when we write $u_i=v_i$ in a presentation we are still in the free group, not in the quotient group.